# Quadrature error estimate

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider a function $f$ on $I = [a,b]$, see below for details. Subdivide $I$ in a uniform grid of size $h$, and consider the expression $h\sum_k ||f(x_k)||^2$, $x_k$ being the equally spaced nodes of the discretization.

I would like to prove that $$h\sum_k ||f(x_k)||^2\leq C \left ( \int_I||f||^2 + h^2\int_I||f'||^2\right )$$

Some details about the notation: to be precise, $f$ is a vector valued function, say, $f:I\rightarrow V$, the norm is the $V$ norm, and $f \in H^1(I,V)$. I think this detail is not absolutely necessary, as I expect the same argument with $V=\mathbb{R}$ to work in the vector valued case.

Using Taylor expansions, the best that I could get follows. We have:

$$h\sum_k ||f(x_k)||^2 =  \int_I||f||^2 + \sum_k \left (h||f(x_k)||^2-\int_{I_k}||f||^2\right)$$

For a single $k$:

$$h||f(x_k)||^2-\int_{I_k}||f||^2 \leq \int_{I_k}|||f(x_k)||^2-||f||^2|\\\leq||f||_\infty\int_{I_k}||f(x_k)-f||\\\leq C \int_{I_k}\int_{x_{k-1}}^x||f'||dtdx\\\leq C||f'||_{L^2(I_k)}\int_{I_k}|x-x_{k-1}|^{1/2}dx\\\leq C||f'||_{L^2(I_k)}h^{3/2}$$

From here I don't get exactly what I want: the first derivative is not squared and the order is at most $3/2$. Can anyone help out in seeing where my estimation could be improved?

Thanks!

Comment: $\| f(x_k)-f(x) \|$ should be $O(x-x_k)$ not $O((x-x_k)^{1/2})$. (You can see that by considering something simple like $f(x)=x$ with $V$ being $\mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: @Ian We don't know whether $f'$ is bounded

Comment: @carmelo : per assumptions, $f$ is smooth on $I$, thus $f'$ continuous on a bounded closed interval.

Comment: Well, fix the first sentence of the question, then; you said it's smooth, so I treated it like it's smooth.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I fixed the post

Comment: I am not so sure that you can expect any better because the relevant Sobolev embedding here is into $C^{0,1/2}$ and no higher, thus $\| f(x_k)-f(x) \|$ shouldn't be expected to be any smaller than $O(|x-x_k|)$.

Comment: @Ian Interesting, right. I think that if the estimate is true, then I'm losing precision when treating $a^2-b^2$ as $(a-b)(a+b)$. Let me point in any case to the source of the problems, the first estimate at page 10 https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.05183.pdf .

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke, I meant to say that increment shouldn't be expected to be any smaller than $O(|x-x_k|^{1/2})$.

Comment: So abstractly, $f\in H^1(I)$ with the norm square equal to the right side, then the evaluation operators $f\mapsto f(x_k)$ are bounded linear operators, thus so is the value vector for all the values at the $x_k$. Is there an expectation that $C$ is independent of $h$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Just to be in line with the notation of the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.05183.pdf (p. 10, first line) I got the estimate from, $f \in H^1(I, H^1(\Omega))$, and yes, the constant $C$ should be independent of $h$. The estimate itself is needed to prove the convergence of the backward euler scheme in energy norm, so that $h$ is actually a $\delta t$ in the link.